# JavaFX know the state of scene (open or close)

Tags: java, database, javafx, scene, stage

Main window
[image]

I have a 'main' window which has a TableView (data loads from a database), when I click the new button on the main window, it opens a new window on exactly on top of the main window (with a transparent background).

New window
[image]

The problem is after I add a new booking, it inserts the value into the database then closes the new window, however the table on the main window does not refresh, I only see the new data unless I reopen the main window.

I have a loadDataFromDB() function on my main windows controller, when I call that function from the new window, I get a null pointer error.

main window:

```
public void loadDataFromDB(){
    try {

        System.out.println("Salman");
        String query = "SELECT * FROM bookings";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            data.add(new Sessions(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2),
                    rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6)));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    table.setItems(data);
}
```

new window

```
private void bookBtnClicked(){

    //after inserting data to DB

    MainWindow a = new MainWindow();
    a.loadDataFromDB();
}
```

I know my way of solving this is not how it should be done, however I cannot come up with any other solution. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: In which instruction are you getting the null pointer exception? Can you post the stack trace? Also the fact that you are creating a new `MainWindow` instead of reusing the existing one is suspicious.

Comment: heres a link to my error - http://docdro.id/M96J0TK

 ....For the creating of MainWindow, if I call a function a.test() which just has a sysout, it works, but calling the loaddb function doesnt.

Comment: The stack trace you posted does not show the instruction causing the exception... The problem of creating a new `MainWindow` is that you might not initialize all the needed variables. Is there a reason of creating a new `MainWindow` instead of reusing the current one?